# Why is Store.getState() returning 'any' type after using rootReducer with combinedReducers?

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-reducers

I am trying to use a root reducer to wrap my combined reducers in order to reset them on reset store action.
However, after using root reducer I am unable to directly access reducers by `Store.getState().recuder1`
Typescript does not give me any errors because `Store.getState()` is returning `any` type. How can I get the type of `combinedReducers` in `Store.getState()` after using `rootReducer`?

Any guidance would be appreciated

```
const combinedReducers = combineReducers({
    reducer1,
    reducer2,
    reducer3
});

const rootReducer = (state, action) : ReturnType<typeof reducer> => {
    if (action.type === RESET_STORE) {
        return combinedReducers(undefined, action)
    }
    return combinedReducers(state, action);
}

export default rootReducer;
```

This is how store is being created

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        __REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__?: typeof compose;
    }
}

const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

export default store;
```

Before using the root reducer I only passed `combinedReducers` to the store and I could get all reducers from `Store.getState().reducer1`/`reducer2` etc. It helps me in development process because I could access the reducers and their respective properties directly.

Comment: Try `typeof combinedReducers`

Comment: I have tried that as well, has not worked

Answer (score 1):

My primary advice would be to switch from the old legacy `createStore` method to Redux Toolkit's `configureStore`.  Not only does `configureStore` automatically set up the Redux DevTools extension for you, it has significantly better type inference than `createStore` does:

- https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today
- https://redux.js.org/usage/migrating-to-modern-redux

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight! I will surely check out